# Rails - Devise image upload failed / images deleted at every push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I've push my rails app on Heroku. It was perfectly working on local, but on Heroku, after many problems it's working now ! I'm happy, but I've 2 problems:

**First**, in my `Edit` user by Devise when I upload an profile pic, I get this error :

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:44:in `update'
```

and so on.

I don't have generate the Devises controllers, but if anyone has an idea !?

**And my second problem**, after any push on heroku, all my images previously upload on the app, are missing.
Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: `heroku logs
2014-05-26T12:40:39.419287+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:44:in `update'`  and so on , on many lines. Nothing more

Answer (score 0):

This is because any `image` or `attachment` uploaded to `Heroku` reside there for a few minutes, after that heroku automatically deletes the data, you need to store your images in `Amazon S3` bucket. Details are in this question.

[everytime push to heroku, images is not showed ,paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425843/everytime-push-to-heroku-images-is-not-showed-paperclip)

Comment: well ok, images show a time, so I going to do that. Thank you ! And for the image upload for profile pic ( the error I posted ) I don't know why, this things crash just for the updload of image